External monitor isn't connecting with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I am using below Linux Distribution.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
I recently bought a samsung Odyssey G8 monitor. While trying to connect it with my Ubuntu Laptop. Its not connecting. Is there any way to connect the monitor with the laptop ? Thanks in advance.

Likely there are driver issues with your video card.  What video card or laptop model is this?
